# Why are politicians and statesmen reticent to challenge the theory behind "Too Big To Fail"?

Tags: united-states, financial-crisis

Why are politicians and statesmen reticent to challenge the theory behind "Too Big To Fail"? It seems that "Too Big To Fail" is the mainstream theory on how to best handle a big bank on the verge of collapse; however, it doesn't have a strong theoretical backing behind it as the following research paper suggests:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1057/jbr.2010.15

> Too big to fail (TBTF) is a doctrine stipulating that big firms
> (particularly financial institutions) cannot be allowed to fail
> because of the potential adverse impact the failure may have on the
> rest of the sector and the economy at large. When they are in trouble,
> financial institutions utilise the language of fear to demand the
> privilege of TBTF at a significant cost to taxpayers. From the
> perspective of costs and benefits, the TBTF doctrine must go the way
> of the dinosaurs.

So how come politicians are reticent to challenge the status quo and be willing to break up large banks when a crisis hit?

Comment: Can you add evidence that politicians and statesmen are reticent to challenge the theory behind "too big to fail" to the question?

Comment: There's nothing to challenge really. It's the logical decision to make in that situation because well if the institution goes down, it will likely cost a whole lot more money cleaning up the mess. By definition, "Too big to fail describes a business or business sector deemed to be so deeply ingrained in a financial system or economy that its failure would be disastrous to the economy."

Comment: A more important question might be why are we allowing companies to become TBTF?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Testing theories like "Too Big To Fail" is an incredibly high-stakes affair. Voters tend to ignore status quos being maintained, but reward/punish very strongly how leaders perform during crises. Consider the possible outcomes:

1. Nothing much happens beyond the collapse of a large firm, short-run job losses and economic activity damage are minor and rapidly compensated for.
2. The economy suffers modest damage as the result of a large financial firm going under, but after a period of economic slowdown the economy adapts and recovers.
3. The economy itself completely collapses, possibly taking the political structure down with it in the ensuring chaos, at the minimum you've got another Great Depression.

Under this list of possible outcomes, #1 is your "win condition."  TBTF was false, and you've proven this to be the case. What are the rewards reaped by a politician?

1. Not much. Some super-wonky academics applaud the steely-eyed insight and steadfast commitment to principles, but by and large the voters don't notice and don't care.
2. Penalty. The politician is blamed for some portion of the economic slowdown, regardless of whether or not this is a fair attribution. An even smaller portion of super-wonky types might applaud the move as 'good in the long run' but by and large the politician receives criticism that means they need to work harder to get re-elected.
3. The politician loses their job, possibly their life depending on how bad things get, and how many rocks fall.

Even before we factor in Game Theory elements such as [the Minimax Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), which is a common regret-avoidance scheme adopted by most people under most circumstances, this is a really, really bad set of options. At best nothing happens, at worst, everything goes to hell.

If you don't test TBTF, your possible outcomes look like this:

1. Nothing much happens, super-wonky types accuse you of wasting resources in a bailout, you face some political heat for "being in the pocket of big banks," which you have to work to overcome when seeking re-election.
2. The effort to prop up the big banks fails, leading to the #2 or #3 scenario above, but this time you can claim that you "tried" and shift blame to other actors.  Maybe you have to fight for re-election but so does everyone else so it's a wash.

In these cases the common thread is that you are almost certainly going to have to answer, politically, for your decision - but this is *par for the course in politics*. This is something you're already demonstrably good at confronting (you won election, after all), and so these negatives play against your strengths.

In short, the political incentives for risking the total collapse of the economy are not strong enough to make even tiny likelihoods of those worst cases tolerable. At best you get a thankless outcome and maybe some good moral feelings, privately.

The selection bias among elected officials is for risk aversion and preference for the status quo unless the political system has recently been shocked by a crisis that is long-lasting enough to influence a whole election cycle (in the U.S. that's 2-6 years), and thus result in leaders chosen explicitly to confront the crisis (where the incentives and motives are distorted from the norm and thus can justify bold actions like testing TBTF).

Comment: There's a possible #3 for not testing TBTF: The effort to prop up the bank fails catastrophically and leads to you being blamed for the ensuing crash; rather than getting to say "I tried to fix it." it looks like you broke it.  Your opponents would get to say the collapse of that firm would just be a palpitation and you made it a full-on heart attack.

Comment: That's still within the realm of 'politics as normal' normal, though. So it's still going to be the preferred #3 to the option where you stuck your neck out and landed there.